# Move from one view to another on button click----?

Tags: ios4

I am new commer to IPhone and developed an app "display next and previous image on button click in single view based application".i want, on run my app"one start button and welcome message view" and then clicking on start button, want to move on my already developed application what i have made with Next and Back Button which are showing the next and previous images properly. Also i want, on button click (start), automatically images moves next without 
clicking on Next images after some interval of time(5 sec) so that user may use the manually to move from one image to another or automatically after some interval of time.

Thanks in advance to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undertand what your are saying with "on my already developed app". I you want to move between views avoid Sin

I recommend you to check UIScrollView reference guide and check the Sample Code that Apple provides.

[UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

To move between imagen using non gesture detections you can also perform some animations using 
UIView animations on the IBAction of the buttons.

I'm sure that if take a look around at apples samples and guides you will develop the app so fast.

Comment: "on my already developed app" means i have made an app in IPhone which functions like a slide.on click to next and previous button we move on the next images, i want in that application,when i start the app show just one button of Start and after clicking on that i move on to my already made app about i have told u, on uiview controller i have three button now next,previous and next how can i hide next and previous button just to show the start button which will take the user to the my 2 other button.